# LE_POWER_OFF_HEADER default alert using CoreBluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using **Core Bluetooth** on my project and all works fine, but when the bluetooth on my device is disabled, I get an alert with the text `LE_POWER_OFF_HEADER` and with the buttons "settings" and "cancel". **I would like change the text and the language.**

It seem like a default alert and I can't change it.

The alert just pops up when the central state is `poweredOff`. I use this function to check the Central Manager's state:

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{ 
NSString *messtoshow;

switch (central.state) {
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"State unknown, update imminent."];
        break;
    }
    case CBCentralManagerStateResetting:
    {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent."];
        break;
         }
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
         {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy"];
        break;
         }
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
         {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy"];
        break;
         }
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
         {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bluetooth is currently powered off."];
        break;
         }
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
         {
        messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use."];
        [mgr scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180D"]] options:nil];
        [mgr retrieveConnectedPeripherals];

        //--- it works, I Do get in this area!

        break;
    }   

}
NSLog(messtoshow); }
```

Comment: I guess you just tried on the Simulator (where I get this message too). With my app, on my device (french localisation), I have something like that (approximative traduction): "Activate Bluetooth to let "YouAppName" to connect to accessories."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with device, you will get proper message in localized language.